# How to check the user role in the WP database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am developing a script that is going to check a get request against our WP database.  I have been able to get by just fine until now.

Now I need to check the role associated with the email from the get request in the database.  As seen [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) I know the user role is stored in the wp_usermeta table in the meta_value columns.

I need to run a conditional in my script where if the user role is subscriber then I will echo out "Disabled" and if it is our custom role ntnw_member then I will echo out "Enabled".

Here is what I see in the field for the meta_value column just for an example:

```
a:1:{s:11:"ntnw_member";b:1;}
```

I just need to get the part in between the double quotes and check if it is equal to either subscriber or ntnw_member.

here is attempt at the query - Note the checkRole variable is where I am getting stuck:

```
/**************************************************
    Get our request and test against database
**************************************************/
if(isset($_GET["email"])) {

    $userEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET["email"]);

    //check email against database
    $checkEmail = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from wp_usermeta WHERE meta_value = '$userEmail'") or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connect));

    if(mysqli_num_rows($checkEmail)>0){

     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($checkEmail, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

        //get the user_id from database
        $userID = $row[user_id];

        $subscriber = Array(
            'subscriber' => 1
        );

        $ntnwMember = Array(
            'ntnw_member' => 1
        );

        $checkRole = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = '$userID' AND meta_value = '$ntnwMember'") or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connect));

        if ($checkRole){
          echo 'Enabled';
        } else {
          echo 'Disabled';
        }

    } //end while $row
} else {
    //if email address does not match anything on file, kill this script
    die('Failed: Your email address does not match our records');
} //end if if(mysqli_num_rows($checkEmail)>0){}

} //endif isset
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$checkRole would return false when there's error.

Instead, use mysqli_num_rows to check if there's any row returned.

```
$userID = $row["user_id"];

$sql = "select * from wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = '" . $userID . "' AND meta_value LIKE '%ntnw_member%'";

$checkRole = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connect));

if (mysqli_num_rows($checkRole)>0){
  echo 'Enabled';
} else {
  echo 'Disabled';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @ydoow, doesnt your suggestion just check to see if the row exists?  I tried it and it echos out Enabled no matter if the role is subscriber or ntnw_member, I just need it to find out which role the user has.  If it is subscriber or anything else it should print "Disabled" and if it is ntnw_member then it should print "Enabled".

Comment: @Derek then you have to revise the query logic to check for 'ntnw_member'

Comment: Ok, I tried a different approach and updated my code above and the query, would you mind taking a look and seeing what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're fetching data from a column in the row, it should be $userID = $row["user_id"];

Comment: Thank you SOOOO Much! Works like a charm and I see what I did wrong.  Thanks again